# Tailwind CSS table header not respecting text-right

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, text-alignment

I'm using tailwindcss to generate code for a table, but I can't get the headers to respect the `text-right` / `text-left` / `text-center` directives.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3u2jgqoc/

Is there a way to line up the header name so that it would match with the column? (In the example I've set the `Address` header to `text-right` since it's the most obvious that it's actually aligning left, but I'd probably want to align the date header as `text-right`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you don't need the `flex` class, but having `block` instead.